# Definition of reflexive spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm currently studying this for an exam and I was wondering why the definition states: "Let E be a Banach space, then it's called reflexive if the canonical injection $J:E\rightarrow E^{**}$ is surjective."

Why must $E$ be a Banach space? My guess is that if $E$ isn't a Banach space then there's some way to see that $J$ can't be surjective, is it correct? How?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398970/show-reflexive-normed-vector-space-is-a-banach-space).