# A reflexive Banach space is separable iff its dual is separable

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(X,||\cdot||)$ be a reflexive Banach space. Prove that $X$ is separable if and only if $X'$ (the dual space of $X$) is separable. Does anyone have a hint for me? I have no idea where to begin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following theorem should be found in any textbook on Banach spaces / basic functional analysis, so you should be able to work out the proof and/or look it up.

**Thm:** Let $X$ be a Banach space. If $X^\prime$ is separable, then $X$ is separable.

Once you prove such theorem, your question becomes an easy corollary.

Comment: Why do we need X to be complete?

Comment: Good question: we don't! If $X$ is a normed linear space (not necessarily complete), and $X'$ is separable, then $X$ is separable. But notice that the dual of a normed linear space is a Banach space, so to go back to the original question: if $X$ is reflexive then it has to be complete. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398970/show-reflexive-normed-vector-space-is-a-banach-space

Comment: In general $L(X,Y)$ is complete whenever $Y$ is a Banach space right?

Comment: Yes: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2057758/14794

Answer (score 0):

Check on this book of functional analysis
[http://www.amazon.com/Introductory-Functional-Analysis-Applications-Kreyszig/dp/0471504599](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471504599)

Page 245 $\rightarrow$ $\mathbf{Theorem\,of\,Separability\,in\,Normed\,Space}$