# Non-complete and non-reflexive normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, normed-spaces

I am searching for an examples of a normed space that is non-complete and non-reflexive, but separable. My idea was to somehow build an infinite dimensional space out of the rationals, such that we get separability and non-completeness from the rationals with norm the absolute value. But I do not really know how to do that. Can anyone provide such an example?

Comment: Doesn't $\bigcup_n \Bbb{R}^n$ with the euclidean metric cut it?

Comment: Why is that not complete?

Comment: Any reflexive space is necessarily complete (I'm only thinking about complete normed base field here). Hence if you have an incomplete normed space it automatically is not reflexive. The example Rob Arthan gives is sometimes called $c_{00}(\Bbb N)$ or the space of compactly supported functions $\Bbb N\to \Bbb R$. Give it norm $\|f\|=\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}|f(n)|$.In this space the sequence:
$$f_n = m\mapsto \begin{cases}\frac1m & m≤n\\0& m>n\end{cases}$$
is Cauchy as you can easily check ($\|f_n-f_m\| = \frac1{\min(n,m)}$), but it does not admit any limit.

Comment: @s.harp: thanks. As I am sure you know, your counter-example to completeness works with the euclidean norm too, but the proof isn't quite as simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show that $\Bbb{R}^* = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} \Bbb{R}^i$ viewed as an inner product space with the induced norm is not complete as follows.

View $\Bbb{R}^*$ as the set of all sequences $\mathbf{v} = (v_1, v_2, \ldots)$ where $v_i\in \Bbb{R}$ for every $i$ and where $v_i = 0$ for all but a finite number of $i$.
$\Bbb{R}^*$ has an orthormal basis comprising the vectors $\mathbf{e}_1 = (1, 0, \ldots), \mathbf{e}_2 = (0, 1, 0, \ldots), \ldots$. Consider the sequence of vectors $(\mathbf{v}_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined by:
$$\mathbf{v}_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} {\mathbf{e}_i \over i!}
$$
Then for $n \ge m$ we have:
$$
\|\mathbf{v}_n - \mathbf{v}_m\|^2 = \sum_{i = m + 1}^n{1 \over (i!)^2}
$$
Since the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} {1 \over (i!)^2}$ converges (by comparison with the standard series representation for $e = \exp(1)$) this shows that the sequence  $(\mathbf{v}_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence. But it can have no limit in $\Bbb{R}^*$: if $\mathbf{v} = (v_1, v_2, \ldots) \in \Bbb{R}^*$, there is an $n$ such that $v_i = 0$ for all $i \ge n$, and then, with $\epsilon = {1 \over 2n!}$, $\|\sum_{i=1}^m\mathbf{v}_i - \mathbf{v}\| > \epsilon$ for every $m \ge n$, so $\mathbf{v}$ is not the limit of the sequence $(\mathbf{v}_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

As pointed out in the comments, as $\Bbb{R}^*$ is not complete it cannot be reflexive. See [Show reflexive normed vector space is a Banach space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398970/show-reflexive-normed-vector-space-is-a-banach-space) for a proof.